# How to replace null results in sql query result table with a string?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a way to replace "null" values in a result table with a string like "Empty"?
Similarly, can we generalize this to replacing a given string or output type with a replacement?

E.g.
Original result:

```
   Dog  Cat Other  
1  1    0   5  
2  5    6   null  
3  45   8   4
```

New result after replacement:

```
   Dog  Cat Other  
1  1    0   5  
2  5    6   N/A  
3  45   8   4
```

Where N/A is the new string.

Clarification:
I am not looking to update the actual data in the table. I only want the printed query result to replace the null values.

Comment: Use `Coalesce([Other], 'N/A')`  If it is something other than a string datatype, you can also do `Coalesce(Str([Other]), 'N/A')`

Comment: Yeah there is a way, if you were to alter the columns and make them not null

Comment: Do you want to update the table? Or just use it in a `SELECT` query?

Comment: Only if you cast the presumably numeric `Other` column to string. Should be done in your application.

Comment: OK someone clearly went on a downvote spree for no reason..

Comment: @ryekayo Yeah lots of unnecessary down votes :( ill try and fix that!

Comment: @bluefeet Hi there, the post that has bee listed here as duplicate is slightly different than what I am asking here. I am not looking to update the actual data in the table. I only want the printed query result to replace the null values. Hope this clears it up. If you have downvoted, please reconsider. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom Have you tried the code in the duplicate?  If it doesn't work, then explain why it isn't solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
COALESCE (str(<columnName>),'Empty')
```

this will use column value if not not null and 2nd argument if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ISNULL function:

```
ISNULL([Other], 'N/A')
```

An application:

```
SELECT [Dog], [Cat], ISNULL([Other], 'N/A')
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Can anybody explain the down voting in every post/comment of this question?

Comment: Not the downvoter but this answer and the others assumes that `Other` is already a string not numeric.

Comment: That's fair, but I'm pretty sure that ISNULL should work in t-sql. 
Can anyone try it? I'm not able to try the example right now.

Comment: If the datatypes are not the same, you're going to get an error. You can't have a string in a numeric column.

Comment: Even if he wants to display data, without saving it? 
So, the question has no solution, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, there is a solution.  The duplicate question shows it, your answer is wrong if the column is numeric. You'd have to cast the number to a string to make it work.

Comment: Ok, I understand: I've missed the cast. Thank you for letting me known.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the `SELECT Other` with

```
CASE WHEN Other IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE Other END
```